Any way to automate filling circles into gaps on a circle grid with some missing circles
I have a grid of circles with holes. I copy and paste circles into the holes. Is there any way this could be automated? I have a script to remove hidden circles behind circles so maybe its the case of finding a way to populate all then remove the ones behind. Just need to know if its possible really. Thanks for any guidance.
i copy and paste currently in illustrator
